# Refused to apply stylesheet because its a MIME type, running off of ATOM.io onto Google Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, atom-editor

I'm a new programmer and need some help. I'm trying to launch a website and my stylesheet won't load. The error looks like this:

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/home.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I know that there are other similar errors reported, but I am running off of Atom.io onto a Google Chrome browser. Not sure if it has anything to do with my IDE or browser but every other solution I have seen has not worked for me. I'm running node.js on the backend and this is my code:

```
var express = require('express'),



`app = express(),
bodyParser    = require('body-parser'),
mongoose      = require("mongoose"),
passport = require('passport'),
flash = require('connect-flash'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


//index
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('home')
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Your personal website has started")

}); `
```

Can anyone help me out? My front end code looks like this as well:

```
<html lang = 'en'>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
  <link href ='/stylesheets/home.css' rel ='stylesheet' type = 'text/css'></link>
</head>
```

Thanks!
Jake

Comment: Can you include the full HTTP response headers for /stylesheets/home.css?

Comment: Running express with `DEBUG=* node index.js` might give a clue as to what express could be doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Josh,
The header looks like this:                                                          
Provisional headers are shown
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0; Pixel 2 Build/OPD3.170816.012) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Mobile Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in server file:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Use this code in home.ejs file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css" />
```